# How many $m$-length strings over $\{0,1\}$, with at least $p$ $1$'s there are?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many $m$-length strings over $\{0,1\}$, with at least $p$ $1$'s
>   there are?

My answer is $\sum^m_{k=p} \binom{m}{k}$, but is there a close-form answer, without summation?

Comment: Unluckily, no. It is a quantile for a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 165 of *Concrete Mathematics* the authors say: "...there is no closed form for the partial sum of a row of Pascal's triangle."

**Reference:** *Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science*, by Ronald Graham, Donald Knuth, and Oren Patashnik.